# How to return Linq expression as a List?

Tags: c#, linq

How to return below code into List

```
public List<tbl_Employee> getProgramNames()
{
    IQueryable<tbl_CentralLookup> data = db.tbl_Employee.Where(c => c.EmpName == "sam").Select(o => new { o.LookupId, o.EmpName });       
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method's return type is List of `tbl_Employee`. So make sure your LINQ expression is also returning the same type data.

```
public List<tbl_Employee> getProgramNames()
{
    return  db.tbl_Employee.Where(c => c.EmpName == "sam").ToList();
}
```

Assuming `db.tbl_Employee` of `DbSet<tbl_Employee>` type.

Also i suggest you follow PascalCasing for C# methods. So i would rename `getProgramNames` to `GetProgramNames` :)

**EDIT** : *As per the question in comment*

> How to specify a column names. I want to retrieve data only for two
>   columns.

If you want only 2 columns, create a DTO for that data structure and use that for projecting the data in your LINQ expression.

```
public class EmployeeBasicInfo
{
  public int Id { set;get;}
  public string FirstName { set;get;}
}
```

Now change your method to return a collection of this DTO instead of the entity.

```
public List<EmployeeBasicInfo> getProgramNames()
{
    return  db.tbl_Employee.Where(c => c.EmpName == "sam")
              .Select(x=> new EmployeeBasicInfo { Id=x.Id, FirstName = x.EmpName })
              .ToList();
}
```

Assuming your `tbl_Employee` entity class has an `Id` property of type `Int`

Comment: Thank you. and How to specify a column names. I want to retrieve data only for two columns.

Comment: @ShakeerHussain See the updated answer.

Comment: Hi , I don't have these two fields. then how to write select statement? public int Id { set;get;}
  public string FirstName { set;get;}

Comment: Create dto with those 2 fields (as i explained in the answer) and return a list of that from your method.